# Update Query With If Exists

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I am trying to write a query that will update my table `#master12.cg` when it is null.  So here are my steps needed:

> 1) Check if `#master12.uid` exists in `#check1.dasboot` and if it does, then update `#master12.cg` with that value
>   2) Check if `#master12.uid` exists in `#check.uid` and if it does update `#master12.cg` with the value in `#check2.redbluegreen`
>   3) If `#master12.uid` does not exist in either table then just leave `#master12.uid` as null

I have tried this query

```
Update #master12
Set [cg] = case 
            when exists (Select [dasboot] FROM [#check1] WHERE [#master].    [uid] = [#check1].[uid])
            when not exists (Select [redbluegreen] FROM [#check2] WHERE     [#master12].[uid] = [#check2].[uid]
       else [#master12].[cg]
       end
WHERE [#master12].[cg] IS NULL
```

However this query presents an error of:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'when'.
>   Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'else'.

How should I write this update statement so that the checks listed above are performed and my table is updated accordingly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLServer [case when](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/ms181765.aspx) statement doesn't work like that. You need a condition, and then a result. Your query only has a condition.

You could rewrite your query like that :

```
Update #master12
Set [cg] = [dasboot] 
from #master12 m
join [#check1] c1 on m.[uid] = c1.[uid]
WHERE m.[cg] IS NULL

Update #master12
Set [cg] = [redbluegreen] 
from #master12 m
join [#check2] c2 on m.[uid] = c2.[uid]
WHERE m.[cg] IS NULL
```

Or maybe in a single one like :

```
Update #master12
Set [cg] = isnull([dasboot], [redbluegreen])
from #master12 m
left join [#check1] c1 on m.[uid] = c1.[uid]
left join [#check2] c2 on m.[uid] = c2.[uid]
WHERE m.[cg] IS NULL
```

But it will also depend on what you want when you have a uid value present in both tables #check1 and #check2 and which value you want to be used for the update.

Comment: If an instance occurs when the uid exists in both tables, I want to use teh value from #check1.  That was a good catch, I had not thought of that scenario.

Comment: Quick update to your syntax.  The individual updates in the where clause should be [m] not the fully qualified name.  The syntax as is presents an error.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with your case. The syntax is

```
CASE 
    WHEN condition THEN value
    WHEN condition THEN value
    ...
    ELSE value
END
```